# Use Propel instead of Eloquent in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, integration, propel

I have started project in Laravel 5.2 based on [Laravel Framework 5 Bootstrap 3 Starter Site](https://github.com/mrakodol/Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site). I have successful upgraded to latest 5.2 laravel version.
Right now I want to use Propel 2 instead of Eloquent. 
Is there much work with replacing it? How about Auth model? Any traps or dead ends?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: https://github.com/propelorm/PropelLaravel

Comment: Already integrated this package and managed to create schema and models based on db. But now I would like to move further and keep working functionality of Authentication.

Comment: https://github.com/propelorm/PropelLaravel#auth